# Graph view in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

how to achieve ancestry hourglass tree view in flutter
I want a ancestry hourglass tree view in flutter,
I used Graph View package I want orientation to be like a combination on both Left right and Right Left Orientation .The problem in my code is while adding its perfectly adding but on left side its collapsing the whole graph view .If anyone know other packages also let me know?

Comment: Please add an image of what you are trying to achieve and also what you have tried so far

Comment: i added the url of image .  https://cdn.windowsreport.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/family_tree_software_myheritage_family_tree_builder.jpg